# How to pass system property values to a processBuilder?

Tags: java, arguments, runtime, parameter-passing, processbuilder

Java's Runtime class allows named system property values to be sent as command line arguments when running a jar. Like below:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar -DiName=ABC C:\\Test.jar");
```

I am trying to move from Runtime to ProcessBuilder to achieve the same functionality. Need advice on what the correct way to do this is.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java",  "-jar",  "C:\\Test.jar").start();
```

In the above code, how can I pass the "iName"?

The reason I am moving from Runtime to ProcessBuilder is, the java program that triggers this Runtime code is not working in a specific production environment which is using 1.8.0_40 JDK.

Comment: What is the "iName"?

Comment: obviusly it should be `("java","-DiName=ABC",  "-jar",  "C:\\Test.jar")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder-java.lang.String...-).

There it is stated clearly that the `ProcessBuilder` Constructor can be of the form `public ProcessBuilder(String... command)` (*for example, see Timothy Truckle comment*) or, equivalently, just a single parameter of type `List<String>`.

So opposite to `Runtime`, which tokenizes one single String, here the `ProcessBuilder`, needs already tokenized parameter list.

Probably, to avoid any future confusion, it would be the best to store the parameters in a variable, for easier modification later. For instance:

```
List<String> params = java.util.Arrays.asList("java", "-jar", "-DiName=ABC", "C:\\Test.jar");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(params).start();
```

Hope this helps in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

```
new ProcessBuilder("java",  "-jar", "-DiName=ABC", "C:\\Test.jar");
```

`ProcessBuilder` receives array (varargs) of parameters, which will be concatenated and executed.